# On giving a certain kind of grading to the polynomial ring over a commutative unital graded ring

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

For any commutative unital ring $R$ , $R[X]$ has a standard $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ grading where the $n$-th component is $R_n:= X^nR[X]$ ; however , given a commutative , unital , graded ring $R$ , I am not sure how to define a canonical grading for $R[X]$ which respects the grading of $R$ in some sense in that the usual inclusion map $i: R \to R[X]$ should be a graded ring homomorphism  .   So my question is :

Let $R$ be a commutative unital $G$- graded ring , where $G$ is a monoid . Does there exist a gradation on $R[X]$ such that the usual inclusion map $i: R \to R[X]$ is a graded ring homomorphism ? Does there also exist a gradation on $R[X]$ satisfying the previous condition and also satisfying that $I[X]$ is a graded ideal of $R[X]$ whenever $I$ is a graded ideal of $R$ ?  If not true in general , then is there any condition on $G$ which answers at least one of the questions in affirmative ?

Comment: What about $R[X]_n=\bigoplus_{i+j=n}R_iX^j$ for the standard grading on $R$?

Comment: @user26857 : okay ... if this gives a grading then I can see that the inclusion map is a graded homomorphism ... but could you please add some details as to why this gives a grading ? and are you taking $G=\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Actually I taken $G=\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$. Is there a problem to check that $R[X]_mR[X]_n\subseteq R[X]_{m+n}$?

Comment: @user26857 : no there is no problem with that .. but I can't immediately see the direct sum ...

Comment: The coefficient of $X^i$ in a sum of homogeneous elements from $R[X]$ which equals zero is a sum of elements from $R$ having different grades. (This is a kind of diagonal, if try to visualize the grading above.)